# use of emplace(args&& ...) in associative containers

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, stdmap, std-pair

I am trying to forward some arguments to do inplace construction of objects . I don't quite get the rationale behind the usage of emplace in associative containers or may be I am just using/thinking in a wrong way. It would be great if someone can share code snippets for usage.

Associative container like map always store an object of kind pair() , and the emplace function says that it will call the constructor of the object stored (which for is always pair in case of maps) by forwarding the arguments. So are we just restricted to provide two arguments (key , value) even if the the function has variadic signature ?

When I used emplace with boost containers before I could pass arguments like :
emplace(arg1, arg2,arg3,arg4) // where arg2,arg3,arg4 were used for constructing the object and arg 1 was key.

when compiling with new gcc-4.6 and c++11 , this breaks
But now I have to do something like :
emplace (arg1 , myobj(arg2,arg3,arg4)); // to make the same code work ;

So the new emplace doesn't do any piece wise construction like boost ? And am I restricted to provide only 2 arguments to maps , because pairs will always accept two argument for their constructors.

Comment: There are still functionality in the standard library that's not fully implements all of C++11. The first version (`emplace(key, arg1, arg2, arg3)`) should work.

Comment: `std::pair` supports [piecewise construction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair), although it doesn't look quite so appealing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So the new emplace doesn't do any piece wise construction like boost ?

What you refer to a "piece wise construction" is not what the standard refers to as piecewise construction, which is:

```
m.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
          std::forward_as_tuple<A1>(arg1),
          std::forward_as_tuple<A2,A3,A4>(arg2, arg3, arg4));
```

This does exactly what you want, forwarding the tuples of args to the first and second `pair` members (but be aware that with GCC 4.6 this requires an accessible copy constructor for each argument type, see http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51183 -- this requirement is fixed for GCC 4.7 by using delegating constructors, not supported by GCC 4.6)

Answer (score 7):

This is indeed a defect in the standard, it is addressed at length in [N3178](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3178.htm).

To quote,

> the only way to construct an object of value_type is to supply exactly
>   two arguments for Key and Value, a pair, or a
>   piecewise_construct_t followed by two tuples.  The original emplace()
>   proposal would have allowed you to specify a Key value followed by any
>   number of constructor arguments for Value.  When we removed the
>   variadic constructor to pair, this ability went away

...

> the status quo is to use piecewise_construct_t if you want to construct an object.

It was [closed as "NAD"](http://cplusplus.github.com/LWG/lwg-closed.html#2006)

Comment: @Xeo, fixing it would be even more ew: _"Fixing this is non-trivial, I think. I think that emplace() for map and multimap need several overloads: one for each overloaded constructor in pair<Key,Value>, and one for the emplace(Key, valueargs...) case. And it probably needs some SFINAE meta-programming to ensure that the last case doesn't override any of the other ones."_