# map::emplace() with a custom value type

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, gcc4.7

I'm having trouble using `map::emplace()`. Can anyone help me figure out the right syntax to use? I am effectively trying to do the same thing as in [this example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/emplace/). Here is my version:

```
#include <map>
using namespace std;

class Foo
{
  // private members

  public:
    Foo(int, char, char) /* :init(), members() */ {  }

    // no default ctor, copy ctor, move ctor, or assignment
    Foo() = delete;
    Foo(const Foo&) = delete;
    Foo(Foo &&) = delete;
    Foo & operator=(const Foo &) = delete;
    Foo & operator=(Foo &&) = delete;
};


int main()
{
  map<int, Foo> mymap;
  mymap.emplace(5, 5, 'a', 'b');

  return 0;
}
```

Under GCC 4.7 (with the `-std=c++11` flag), I am erroring out on the `emplace` line. The [example I linked above](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/emplace/) doesn't say anything about how to deal with custom types instead of primitives.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13689482/use-of-emplaceargs-in-associative-containers

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A container's `emplace` member constructs an element using the supplied arguments.

The `value_type` of your map is `std::pair<const int, Foo>` and that type has no constructor taking the arguments `{ 5, 5, 'a', 'b' }` i.e. this wouldn't work:

```
std::pair<const int, Foo> value{ 5, 5, 'a', 'b' };
map.emplace(value);
```

You need to call `emplace` with arguments that match one of `pair`'s constructors.

With a conforming C++11 implementation you can use:

```
mymap.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, std::make_tuple(5), std::make_tuple(5, 'a', 'b'));
```

but GCC 4.7 doesn't support that syntax either (GCC 4.8 will when it's released.)

Comment: This seems to work fine, even on GCC 4.7. Thanks. FWIW, I used `std::forward_as_tuple()` instead of `std::make_tuple()`, because I think it should be slightly better optimized, but I'm not really sure what the difference is.

Comment: `forward_as_tuple(5, 'a', 'b')` creates `tuple<int&&, char&&, char&&>` and `make_tuple(5, 'a', 'b')` creates `tuple<int, char, char>`. In general `forward_as_tuple` avoids making copies of its arguments and forwards references, but in this case (with `int` and  `char` arguments) the copies created by `make_tuple` are probably cheaper than creating references. It's also less typing :)

Comment: As for C++17,  `map.try_emplace(5, 5,'a','b') `; can be used, too.

Answer (score 3):

GCC 4.7 does not have full support of `emplace` functions.

You can see C++11 support in GCC 4.7.2 [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/libstdc++/manual/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011).

Comment: I was afraid of that. Is what I tried the correct syntax though? Ie, would it work on some other compiler?

Comment: Also, `emplace()` works fine with `map<char, int>` like in the cplusplus.com example.

Comment: @SchighSchagh You might need to `forward_as_tuple`, I'm not sure as I have never used `emplace`.

Comment: It is a valid reason that the call would not work. The fact that you have another is not justification for downvote.

Comment: @SchighSchagh: the cplusplus example doesn't work on `g++-4.7.2` also, I just tested it.

Comment: The linked document is out of date, GCC trunk (which that page refers to) _does_ support `map::emplace`, the correct link for GCC 4.7 is http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/libstdc++/manual/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011

Comment: @JonathanWakely good to know. The link I gave was a bookmark I had.