# C++11 functionality with MinGW

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, mingw

I try to use `emplace()` function for an unordered_map and compiler says that no such function exists.

I put `-std=c+11` and it says `cc1plus.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-std=c+11'`

Can i somehow use C++11 functionality with mingw?

Comment: Try `c++11` instead of `c+11`

Comment: Either that, or try `c++0x`

Comment: Neither works (i allready have c++0x ON)

Comment: 'class std::unordered_map<std::basic_string<char>, dictionaryWord>' has no member named 'emplace'.


Emplace is defined in c++11. So i need to add c++11 support, but when i do it sais:


unrecognized command line option '-std=c+11'

Comment: Well, just look at '-std=c+11'. You only have single plus character here.

Comment: i tried both c++11 and c+11, message is the same

Comment: What version is your MinGW (You can check with `gcc -v`)? `std=c++11` was introduced relatively recently.

Comment: @milleniumbug 4.6.2 (i installed mingw this week)

Comment: @PetrosDrakoulis: Then maybe it's not available on that version. MinGW is up to 4.7.2 now.

Answer (score 14):

From the [GCC documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html)

> C++0x was the working name of a new ISO C++ standard, which was then
>   released in 2011 as C++11 and introduces a host of new features into
>   the standard C++ language and library. This project seeks to implement
>   new C++11 features in GCC and to make it one of the first compilers to
>   bring C++11 to C++ programmers.
>
> C++11 features are available as part of the "mainline" GCC compiler in
>   the trunk of GCC's Subversion repository and in GCC 4.3 and later. To
>   enable C++0x support, add the command-line parameter **-std=c++0x** to
>   your g++ command line. Or, to enable GNU extensions in addition to
>   C++0x extensions, add -std=gnu++0x to your g++ command line. GCC 4.7
>   and later support **-std=c++11** and -std=gnu++11 as well.

So, for gcc 4.3 through 4.6 use -std=c++0x, for later version use -std=c++11. Library support for `map::emplace` was added in gcc 4.8

Comment: same error: 'class std::unordered_map<std::basic_string<char>, dictionaryWord>' has no member named 'emplace'

Comment: I have come to believe that i can not use c++ 11, or at least all of it, with 4.6.

Comment: You will need gcc 4.8 to use `map::emplace`, see e.g. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14075128/mapemplace-with-a-custom-value-type)

Comment: The project i try to compile for windows, was made in Linux Gcc 4.7.2 a month ago. There is emplace() in linux gcc 4.7.2

Comment: @PetrosDrakoulis That's surprising because the [gcc 4.7.2 docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/libstdc++/manual/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011) says that `emplace` is missing for `map`. See also http://ideone.com/dqScM9 Safe bet is to install MinGW 4.8, e.g. from http://nuwen.net/mingw.html

Comment: Thank you. I will try to do so. But i guarantee you that in Linux gcc 4.7.2 with flag -std=c+11 there is emplace() for unordered_map. I participated in a contest 2 weeks ago and with the compiler being 4.7.2 i used it. It's the very program i try to recompile for windows...