# Get_s function not working

Tags: c, mingw-w64, c11, gets, tr24731

My book says the `get_s()` function is a better alternative to the `gets()` function, which is deprecated and should not be used. But, when I try to use the `get_s()` function it always gives me an error:

```
undefined reference to gets_s
```

[This page says something about the gets_s](https://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/103287-how-use-gets_s.html), function that I didn't really understand about it being defined in the `ISO/IEC 99`. Shouldn' t it work with all the compilers? I'm pretty sure I'm using a very recent version of the MinGW compiler.

How should I use this function? Is using the `gets()` or `scanf()` (instead of `scanf_s()`), or `fgets()` over `fgets_s()`, not good?

Comment: "Shouldn' t it work with all the compilers". No, it is not a standard C function. It is Microsoft specific so basically need Visual Studio.

Comment: @kaylum, Is the "ANSI C" different from "microsoft specific" standard?

Comment: @kaylum, Is it ok to not learn about this standards? How do I get more information about the typical number of standards available?

Comment: `gets_s()` is defined in optional Annex K of the C11 (ISO/IEC 9899:2011) standard.  It was previously defined in [TR 27431-1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372980/do-you-use-the-tr-24731-safe-functions).  It was implemented by Microsoft and offered as a standard, but the Unix (POSIX) community wasn't impressed.  C11 unstandardized the `gets()` function — it is no longer part of standard C, though all implementations probably provide it for reasons of 'backwards compatibility'.  It is [never safe to use `gets()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/). If available, `gets_s()` is OK.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, from above comments, I found there were other standards of C. Do we have to learn all of these standards?

Comment: You have to know the environments on which you work — yes.  They're all different.  Knowing the core C standard helps a lot, but you invariably end up using non-standard functions too. It helps if you know when you're using 'non-standard' functions. Annex K of C11, being optional, is not 'core C standard'. Until recently, a lot of MS C support was firmly C90, not even C99. That has improved, but it isn't there yet. MS has its own island of standards. Unix (including Linux) has POSIX to provide a lot of commonality, but there are differences outside that standard. Yes, you learn a lot of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you are right #bumblebee
The gets() function does not perform bounds checking, therefore this function is extremely vulnerable to buffer-overflow attacks. It cannot be used safely (unless the program runs in an environment which restricts what can appear on stdin). For this reason, the function has been deprecated in the third corrigendum to the C99 standard and removed altogether in the C11 standard. fgets() and gets_s() are the recommended replacements.
Never use gets().

source: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets
check weather you included the corresponding header. and one more thing u have to see is that weather you c comiler version is an updated version or the old version that can also create a problem.. so try in a c11 standard ,or a c11 online compiler

Comment: above in the comments it is stated that the function is "microsoft specific", how do I find out the typical number of standards available?

Comment: and do we have to learn all of these standards to be a good C programmer?

Comment: Is MinGW not a C11 compiler?

Comment: @BumbleBee: MinGW is not a compiler; it is an environment.  The C compiler provided with MinGW is GCC.  GCC is a C11 compiler, but the MinGW environment is mostly based on Microsoft's libraries.  Since `gets_s()` is provided by MS, it is surprising that you didn't link successfully.  I'm not sure I can help with why the linking failed.

Comment: c++ is a huge programming language ,but being updated with the latest is a good thing , c++ is flexible and can handle many complexities. Thats why the big 4 {google,facebook,apple etc } still  rely mostly on it . to get a expert level standard takes years. anyways keep going . all  the best .i too started practising recently . please accept my answer if it gave an solution to ur question

Comment: i suggest you to just  try the same program on a online c11 standard compiler and check if its working

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, " implicit declaration of function 'gets_s' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]|", it gives me this warning and errors undefined reference to gets_s()

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, does the GCC also support the elements defined by C11 as optional?

Comment: No idea; I've never used MinGW and don't know what version of GCC it has, etc.  I know in theory what MinGW is.

Comment: @venky513, do you know if the GCC supports the elements defined by C11 as optional?

Comment: which gcc version are you using

Comment: i think this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16136142/c11-functionality-with-mingw

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, is there a page summarizing these optional elements?

Comment: @BumbleBee: I don't know of such a page, no.  There are too many optional bits in too many systems for such a page to be easy to create or maintain.

Comment: @venky513, I've installed the latest version

Comment: I think it could be 6.3(code blocks doesn't show it)

Comment: In order to use `gets_s` you must check if `__STDC_LIB_EXT1__` is defined by the compiler. If not, the function is not supported. Otherwise if defined, it is part of stdio.h

Answer (score 0):

During early 90s or so, `gets()` was found to be flawed by design since it would keep reading data forever until it found the end of a string, which meant it could cause buffer overflows either accidentally or through security exploits.

Therefore `gets` was flagged as an obsolescent function in the C99 standard. Meaning that from the year 1999, people were warned that it should not be used.

The function was removed entirely from the language in the C11 standard, meaning that there was a very generous transit period of no less than 12 years to fix legacy code. It was replaced by `gets_s`, as a safe alternative to be used when porting old code to C11. It takes the buffer size as second parameter.

However, `gets_s` should only be used for such C11 porting reasons, if at all. `gets_s` is part of the optional bounds-checking interface in C11 and compilers need not implement it. The C11 standard recommends to use `fgets` instead:

> Recommended practice
>   The **fgets** function allows properly-written
>   programs to safely process input lines too long to store in the result
>   array. In general this requires that callers of fgets pay attention to
>   the presence or absence of a new-line character in the result array.
>   Consider using **fgets** (along with any needed processing based on
>   new-line characters) instead of **gets_s**.

---

Note that `gets_s` has little to do with the non-standard Visual Studio compiler, even though that compiler happens to support this function, just as the standard conforming compilers that support the bounds-checking interface (`__STDC_LIB_EXT1__`) do.